# dark screen on dell latitude D520

Tags: laptop, dell-latitude

I have Dell Latitude D520 (for 3 years)

and my screen is dark.

I try to set to maximum and still dark.

Is the screen broken? Is it fixable?

Comment: Take a look at these: http://superuser.com/questions/191725/how-have-i-destroyed-my-laptop-backlight and http://superuser.com/questions/5892/my-laptops-backlight-stopped-working

Comment: It's probably just a blown inverter.  I'm not familiar with this model so I can't tell you how difficult it is but it's probably worth your while to investigate the cost of the fix if you really like the machine...

Comment: Diagnosis is the hard part, it could be a bad backlight (CCFL Lamp)...http://www.lcdparts.net/ccfl.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a hardware issue. Thankfully replacing the screen is not very hard and the should be fairly cheap. I recently had to replace one on a latitude e6400 the screen cost $115 direct from Dell and it took me all of 20 minutes to replace. I have replaced the RAM on many D series Latitudes which involves removing the the area around the screen and the keyboard. It is a very simple process just make sure you don't use a metal screwdriver (it will scratch) to pry the front plate off and also be careful with the keyboard. Other than that follow [this](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/latd520/en/sm_en/display.htm#wp1022270) service manual and you will be fine.